While running linux commands/terminal commands from karate, script is getting stuck
while running linux commands as below, script is getting stuck after running the linux commands, and it is not executing the api
PFB code:
@port
Feature: port forwarding Suite Feature


  Background:
    * def jsonData = read('classpath:api-tests/mss/config.json')
    
  Scenario: java cli
    Given url 'http://localhost:8080/merchant-self-service'
    And path '/payment/pay-with-card/authorization'
    And request jsonData.payload
    * def command =
      """
      function(line) {
        var proc = karate.fork({ redirectErrorStream: false, useShell: true, line: line });
        proc.waitSync();
        karate.set('sysOut', proc.sysOut);
        karate.set('sysErr', proc.sysErr);
        karate.set('exitCode', proc.exitCode);
      }
      """
    And command('gcloud --project lover-dev-kubernetes container clusters get-credentials dev-us-west1-cluster --region us-west1 && kubectl config set-cluster gke_lover-dev-kubernetes_us-west1_dev-us-west1-cluster --server=https://dev-us-west1-ingress-nginx.dev.pdx13.lover.network && kubectl config unset clusters.gke_lover-dev-kubernetes_us-west1_dev-us-west1-cluster.certificate-authority-data')
    And command('kubectl port-forward -n merchant-self-service-dev deployment/merchant-self-service 8080:8080 > /dev/null &')
    When method POST
    Then status 200

